# paramiko errno 110, Python script fails to connect from a specific host

Tags: python, paramiko

I have written a paramiko script to batch-transfer files with sftp. The script works fine on my development machine -- [Linux Mint 13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_Mint_releases), using Python 2.7.

When I moved the script to the production system, I found I had to build Python from scratch on it since the system Python was too old. So I built Python 2.7 on it --Centos -- and then attempted to run my script. It failed with a:

```
paramiko.SSHException - Errno 110, connection timeout
```

I've googled for that exception, but didn't find anything that seemed to fit. The script seems to 'hang' and the timeout on the `paramiko.Transport((host, port))` part.

I thought this strange so attempted to do an sftp using openssh from that system, just to assure the remote host was responsive. It was -- and it worked.

So, now I go back to my script and simplify everything so it makes a bare-bones connection .. Still, I get a connection timeout. I don't know how to turn up debug with paramiko. Any suggestions?

Here's the basic script:

```
import os.path
import sys
import traceback
import paramiko
host = 'sftp.host.com'
user = 'user'
pw  = 'password'
storepath = '/home/ftpservice/download' 
is_dir = lambda x: oct(x)[1:3] == '40'
is_file = lambda x: oct(x)[1:3] == '10'
tp = paramiko.Transport((host, 22))
print 'tp is made, connecting '
tp.connect(username=user, password=pw, hostkey=None)
sftp = tp.open_sftp_client()
print 'sftp client made, now listing files'
filelist =  sftp.listdir('.')
print filelist
for i in filelist:
    fs = sftp.stat(i)
    print "file is %s " % i
    print "stmode %s" % sftp.stat(i).st_mode
    if is_dir(sftp.stat(i).st_mode):
        print "%s is a directory " % i
    elif is_file(sftp.stat(i).st_mode):
        print "%s is a file " % i
    else:
        print "no clue what %s is " % i
```